# Mediawiki : Gadgets tab not appearing in appearance

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to use the navigation popup in mediawiki but my mediawiki under appearance tab has no gadgets option and gadget definition is empty.

Special:version shows the following – (bac29ae) 06:39, 5 May 2018. It seems the gadget extension is installed but no gadget tab appears.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Gadgets extension, you also need to define each gadget separately as described in the [Gadgets extensions documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets#Usage).